# Salesforce object fields and how they are displayed

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, fields, standard-objects

I have a question regarding the fields that are displayed when creating an object. For example, when creating the default Campaign object in Sales:

I have 2 pictures below.

**One is when creating an object:** [image: 1]

**The other is after creating the object:** [image: 2]

As you can see, the number of fields on the object that are displayed are increased.

I have the same scenario on a custom object I created:

**Fields of custom object** [image: 3]

**Creating an object:** [image: 4]

**After creating the object:** [image: 5]

The difference is that the fields that are not displayed on the custom object when creating it (status color, total invoice, number of items) are based on a Master-detail relationship between this custom object and another object. They are rollup summary and forumla fields. So they are not displayed when creating the object, but get populated as child objects are created.

When I look at the **Campaign** object in sales, I don't see any relationship between it and other objects. So where are these fields being pulled from? When I looked up the fields in Campaign, they only showed basic information (name, and type). Question is how are these fields being populated and where are they pulled from? Is it through some other means than relationships between objects?

How does SalesForce know, display x fields when creating object, but display y fields after object is created?

Edit: Can't comment so adding here. I understand that certain field types that cannot be edited will not be displayed. But when I look at the Campaign fields, they only show type as Currency (not rollup-summary or some other field type that is expected). How is that possible in this scenario? Does a numeric field with a formula not get displayed since its dependent on a calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Fields that cannot be edited due to field types (formulas, roll-up summaries, etc) will not be shown on the edit page and only on the detail page since their value are dependant on the value entered on the edit page